RandomizedSearchCV is taking very long long time to run
I am trying to search for a best parameter combination for my model (RandomForestRegressor) using RandomizedSearchCV. But I am facing a challenge. RandomizedSearchCV seems to be taking eternity before it runs and bring an output. It has been running for a very long time now without any output.
This is the code:
 From sklearn.preprocesing import MinMaxScaler
 X=df.iloc[:,:-1]
 scaler= MinMaxScaler()
 X_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(X)
 X=pd.DataFrame(X_scaled, columns=X.columns, index= X.index)`\
 y=df.iloc[:,-1:]   

 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
 from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
 from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, RandomizedSearchCV
 from sklearn.metrics import r2_score

param_d={"max_depth":[2,3], "n_estimators":[100,400],"min_samples_split":[2,4],
"max_features":["sqrt", "None"],"criterion":["squared_error", "absolute_error"] }
  
Rdfr=RandomForestRegressor(max_samples=0.7, oob_score=True)
Randomsearch=RandomizedSearchCV(Rdfr,param_distributions=param_d,
n_iter=10,scoring="r2", cv=4, n_jobs=-1)

Randomsearch.fit(X,y)
randomsearch.cv_result_
df_result=pd.DataFrame(Randomsearch.cv_result_)
df_result
I am also experiencing the same thing with GridSearchCV.
But for GridSearchCV it is naturally very slow
so I am not bothered. so I decide to switch to RandomizedSearchCV and I am experiencing the same thing .
please I need help.
